Doubt about figure in Visual Complex Analysis book about Conformal = analytic
In the book "Visual Complex Analysis" by Tristan Needham, when explaining that conformal = analytic in section 4.6 there is a point I dont quite understand:
Section 4.6.2 talks about conformality in a region and presents a generric mapping with the following requirements:
(i) is conformal
(ii) sufficiently non-pathological that an infinitessimal line-segment is mapped to another infinitessimal line-segment.
Then he presents the following figure:

From here, he mentions that as we shrink the left triangle towards an arbitrary point, the sides of its shrinking image will resemble straight lines by virtue of (ii).
I understand that if statement (ii) is true then of course as it states, it will eventually map line-segments to line-segments and this is why the triangle edges on the right resemble lines when shrinking.
What I do not understand is where this requirement comes from. For example what about a mapping that just scales down the curved triangle as it is? Then the infinitessimal line-segments on the left would map to infinitessimal arcs on the right. Is such a mapping pathological? What is wrong with this mapping? Maybe this mapping can not exist at all, I am not sure. I just dont see why line-segments need to "obviously" map to line-segments otherwise it is pathological.
I restate: what about a mapping where the image is always the "triangle" with the curved sides and only scaled down keeping the same shape as we shrink the input triangle? That mapping would still be conformal, but then pathological, why is that?
EDIT:
The mapping I was suggesting is the one in the new figure. Now that I "drew" it I am not sure this new mapping would be conformal because the angles don't seem to be conserved. My question was, if this new mapping were to be conformal (which again I am not sure), then infinitessimal line-segments would be mapped to infinitessimal arcs and then the argument used in the book where infinitessimal triangles are mapped to infinitessimal similar triangles, which implies there is  an "amplification" and a "rotation" e.g. a transformation that can be expressed as a complex number, and therefore the mapping is analytic.

So if this new mapping is conformal, the argument used does not hold and then this would imply that there are conformal mappings that are not analytics, which is wrong. So I guess my mistake is in thinking that the new mapping I drew is conformal, right?
Also what would be an example of a mapping that is pathological? e.g that does not transform infinitessimal line-segments into infinitessimal line-segments?
Thank you.

Not sure I understand. A "scaling" mapping $z \mapsto cz$ for $c \in [0,1)$ is obviously not pathological and still maps line segments to line segments (actually, not just "infinitesimal" ones). And except for extra rotation, that remains even true for general $0 \neq c \in \mathbb C$. That's a linear map in every sense, you cannot get less pathological than that.

Thanks for the reply @TorstenSchoeneberg, I edited my question,hopefully it is more clear now and you can give an answer.
